# Messed Up My Primary Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, hard-drive

I'm really sorry if this is a repost, but I couldn't find anybody with my same problem online. I started with a PC running Ubuntu 18 on an SSD (let's call it HDD #1) with the default partition setup and an encryption setup for the largest of the three partitions that holds all the user data (Documents, programs, etc.). I also had another HDD (let's call it HDD #2) that was plugged in that was set up to just be one huge 4TB partition with data on it. HDD #2 can't and shouldn't be booted from. This system was working fine up until...

I decided to format and install Ubuntu on a third HDD (let's call it HDD #3). This went well and I can now boot and run from HDD #3. Unfortunately, after unplugging HDD #3, my PC refuses to boot from HDD #1 anymore. I have tried:

- Changing the boot order of the drives so that HDD #1 boots first
- Directly booting from HDD #1 in BIOS
- Unplugging HDD #2 and HDD #3 and booting both ways from HDD #1

What happens if HDD #3 isn't plugged in is that after BIOS boots up, it sends me straight to GNU GRUB. I'm not sure what to do in there or if I should be doing anything in there at all, I know it's a bootloader but don't know how to use it and don't want to mess anything up by not knowing what I'm doing (all too easy in Linux!).

What did I do wrong? Is there a way I can fix this? Can HDD #1 be accessed ever again?

Comment: If you are booting to GRUB, you should be able to select an operating system if one exists.  Another way to find a "lost" OS is to use a Live USB and run [boot-repair](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows/182863#182863),  You can also inspect your drives on a live USB using the utility "Disks" -- If your encrypted partition is still in tact, you should be able to unlock it and browse the file system --- I would do a backup to external media before doing `boot-repair`, if you are able.

Comment: Can you boot to the system on HDD1 from grub menu while HDD3 is plugged? If so, `sudo grub-install` issued from the system on HDD1 should solve this.

Comment: @Nmath I used a USB to live-boot and looked at it using Disks. Everything seems to be there! I'm having trouble running boot-repair however unfortunately. **When I run the command** sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

**I get this error:**

Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~yannubuntu/ubuntu/boot-repair'.
ERROR: '~yannubuntu' user or team does not exist.

Comment: The [PPA is still active](https://launchpad.net/~yannubuntu/+archive/ubuntu/boot-repair).  It's possible that you might not be connected to the internet or maybe it was temporarily unavailable when you tried.

Comment: The correct add-apt repository command is `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`.

Comment: @Nmath I got the boot utility working, the PPA was only down temporarily like you said. Ran the boot utility and it said it found a partition, however it still isn’t booting unfortunately.

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for the help! I’ll just be reinstalling the os then, seems a lot easier in the long run. I also had an IT professional in person tell me today that even if I found a way to repair it, it likely wouldn’t work quite the same as before, so it looks as though even if I put in the time and fixed the current install it wouldn’t really be worth fixing. Have a good one!